# jQuery toggleClass easing not affecting CSS transform properties

Tags: jquery, css, transform, duration

I would like to...

1. Click an element (.switch)
2. Which toggles a class on another element (.div)
3. The toggled class (.transformy) applies CSS transforms gradually.

I've been able to do this successfully with other CSS classes like background-color, but not transform.

As you can see, the transform applies, but not gradually.

https://jsfiddle.net/ds06sehq/3/

```
$( ".switch" ).click(function() {
$( ".div" ).toggleClass("transformy", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
});
```

How can I have the transform property of the toggled class happen gradually? Certainly willing to try non js/jq options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your div

```
div {
  ..
  transition: all 1s;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

[updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ds06sehq/6/)

Comment: SPARKLE-EYES-HAPPINESS!